# I need to compare/sort two text files

Tags: sort, diff, comm

this is the scenario. I have File1 and File2  and i like to have the outcome in File3.
I'm kind of new to Linux, but so far ive tried to use sort, diff, and comm. but no luck so far.

```
File1.txt File2.txt > File3.txt
```

File1.txt

```
RB0009  8,89
RB0010  5,67
RB0015  4,32
RB0027  6,56
```

File2.txt

```
RB0009  8,89
RB0010  5,67
RB0015  4,32
RB0027  6,56
RB0033  9,78
```

File3.txt

```
RB0009  700111i 8,89
RB0010  700092i 5,67    
RB0015  700148i 4,32
RB0027  700123i 6,56
```

help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are the values in the middle column of File3.txt generated?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment below me, it seems like I misunderstood the question. This *should* give you the expected output:

```bash
paste File1.txt File2.txt | awk '{print $1"\t" "700" NR "i" "\t" $2}' > File3.txt
```

##### Misunderstanding below:

---

If I understand correctly, you have two input files (`File1.txt` and `File2.txt`) and you want to create an output file (`File3.txt`) that contains the sorted and combined content of the two input files?

Assuming that the first column of each file is a unique identifier (e.g., `RB0009`, `RB0010`, etc.), and that you want to combine the two files by matching these identifiers, you could use the `join` command in Linux.

Here's an example command that should accomplish what you're looking for:

```bash
join -t $'\t' -a 1 -a 2 -o auto <(sort File1.txt) <(sort File2.txt) > File3.txt
```

Breakdown of the command:

- `join` is the command we're using to join the two files.
- `-t $'\t'` tells `join` to use a tab (`\t`) as the field separator.
- `-a 1 -a 2` tells `join` to include all lines from both files, even if there are no matches.
- `-o auto` tells `join` to output the fields from both files, separated by a tab.
- `<(sort File1.txt)` and `<(sort File2.txt)` are process substitutions that sort the contents of each file before passing them to `join`. This is important because `join` requires sorted input files in order to work properly.
- `>` redirects the output of the `join` command to `File3.txt`.

The resulting `File3.txt` should contain the combined content of the two input files, sorted by the first column (the unique identifier).

Comment: This does not give the output expected by the OP. It does not create the second column, only the first and third.

Comment: @doneal24 I've updated the answer.

Comment: The updated answer still does not work in my test. The middle column begins with `700` and ends with `i` but the number in between starts at 1 and increments in each row. How would you generate `700092i` as the value on the second row?